# Help in Server Configure

Tags: windows-server-2003

I Install apache 2.2 in my windows server and i want to know what is the ip of my clients . 
what am i going to do ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

You are doing either 1 of 2 things:

1. Looking in your server's [**log files**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html)
2. Reading the value of the REMOTE_ADDR HTTP request header from the client's request.

It depends on what it is that you want to do with the information and how you want to obtain it.  For running access reports or other analytics you're probably doing #1 above.  If you're reading the IP for application level purposes you're probably doing #2 above in conjunction with a CGI script, PHP page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. Are you looking for the internal IP address of the windows server?